# sxtwl Lunar attribute doesn't exist

Tags: python

I'm trying to use the sxtwl library

and I found an example with use the .Lunar()

But, unfortunatelly I got the error

> AttributeError: module 'sxtwl' has no attribute 'Lunar'

When I did

```
dir(sxtwl)
```

I got this list of attributes :

```
['Day', 'Day_fromLunar', 'Day_fromSolar', 'GZ', 'J2000', 'JD2DD', 'JDList', 'SwigPyIterator', 'Time', '_SwigNonDynamicMeta', '__builtin__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '_swig_add_metaclass', '_swig_python_version_info', '_swig_repr', '_swig_setattr_nondynamic_class_variable', '_swig_setattr_nondynamic_instance_variable', '_sxtwl', 'fromLunar', 'fromSolar', 'getLunarMonthNum', 'getRunMonth', 'getShiGz', 'siZhu2Year', 'toJD']
```

What is could be a solution?

Thanks

I check the
https://github.com/yuangu/sxtwl_cpp/blob/master/python/README.md
https://pypi.org/project/sxtwl/

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `lunar` attribute does not exist as it's not present in the list of attributes you have attached...

The example you have seen is most likely incorrect (or it's old).

Thus, the thing you are trying to achieve probably can be done with some other attribute.

If you can share your objective, maybe we can help.

Comment: Hi 
Thanks for your answer
I looking for some "project" which will approve me to get Bazi data based on date/geo 
input : date/geo
output: heawen/earth pillar data